# Finding work done on a spring using Hooke's law (force = constant * distance) and Work equation (work = force * distance)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, spring

From [the lesson](http://my.thinkwell.com/cf/straighterline/?9F82943A3A80B604), they have said that $k$ is constant. Which I'm assuming springs tension is constant?

I've tried (1):

equating work to force * change in distance $(4 = f(x) * \Delta x$), finding $f(x) = \frac{2}{7}$
Then use hooke'ss law to find the spring's constant:

$\frac{2}{7} = k * 14\implies k=\frac{1}{49}$

Thus: Force = $f(x) = \frac {x}{49}$

$\int_{0}^{20} \frac{x}{49}dx = \frac{200}{49}$ which is incorrect.

---

I also tried (2) [following this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262288/finding-work-done-on-a-spring-using-hookes-lawforce-constant-distance-and#:%7E:text=the%20answer%20by-,Floris,-on%20this%20same):

Getting the $k = \frac{4}{14}$ then integrate with $\int_{0}^{20} \frac{4}{14} x dx =\frac{400}{7}$ which is also incorrect.

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong, where my knowledge gap is..?

[image]

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is what k is. In a linear equation like this, k is what is known as a “constant of proportionality”. Funnily enough (although I hope this doesn’t confuse you), the letter k is often used as a general constant of proportionality, but in this equation k is the symbol given to the “Spring constant”. It is a property of the spring. If we rearrange Hooke’s law to F/x = k, we can see that the units of k will be newtons per meter (although I see your lesson was working in pounds and inches...) Basically, k is describing how much force is needed per unit of length that we stretch the spring.

On to your other question:

They tell you that 4J of work is done to stretch the spring by 14 cm.

The formula I would instantly use is W = 1/2kx^2, but I’m not sure if you are familiar with it. It is important to remember in this situation that the force on the spring is increasing as you extend it further. That means, when you calculate work you need to take into account that it is a changing force. When you use W = F(x) * ∆x as you’ve done, you would be working out the average force, not the max. That is fine, but should be noted.

To continue the calculation, I would substitute 4 for work, and 0.14 for ∆x. This is because you have to use meters when working with joules (not centimeters). The force would work out to be 200/7 N.

Then, you would substitute into F = kx. Here, it is important to remember that the formula you used earlier gives the average force, not the maximum (the formula I suggested would give the maximum). Thus, you can use the force 200/7 N, but substitute only half the extension. 200/7 = k*(7/100) and solving for k gives k = 20000/49.

Then you can integrate the equation F = (20000/49)x with limits 0 and 0.2, and this will give you 8.16J. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The force during extension of the spring is not constant.
$F = kx$ means that the force at that very extension or compression $x$ from the equilibrium position is $F$.

The work done is given. You need to determine the spring constant $k$ first by integrating the spring force between the limits $0$ to $x_1$ and equating it to the work done. Then when you have determined the value of $k$ from the given condition, use it to obtain the work done by integrating the spring force within the new integration limits.

Comment: so the lesson is wrong, saying that k is a constant when it actually shouldn't be a constant...?

Comment: $k$ can be assumed to be a constant in this case. The force $F=kx$ is not constant, as it is directly proportional to $x$.

Comment: I see, thanks @mechanic, are you saying force is related to work like how velocity is related to position? We can integrate force to get work? Also is my [working correct in this case](https://ibb.co/Fm1vm2b)?

Comment: @nvs0000 You have made several mistakes like not keeping the units consistent and using the constant of integration in definite integrals where there is no constant of integration. I suggest going back to the textbook and thoroughly going through some worked-out examples.